# Interacting with Zksync sometimes returns an "invalid value for value.blockHash" error

Tags: cryptocurrency

I've been sometimes getting this error while interacting with zksync "invalid value.blockHash" and have been unable to find information about it elsewhere. What's curious to me is that it only happens sometimes, not all the time and it also happens with different smart contracts interactin in zksync that belong to different applications.

Has anyone encountered this and maybe knows of a way to deal with it?

Comment: This is a programming question, so off-topic on here. Assuming this is about Etherum's [zkSync](https://zksync.io/) then the [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask. Be sure to provide them with the exact error message (and stack trace, if available), though.